# SilverStripe many to many translation issue

Tags: php, frameworks, silverstripe

I have SilverStripe project (3.1.12 both cms and framework).

I'm using `silverstripe-translatable` extension for cms in order to translate things on my website.

I have created two page types: `ProductPage` and `CategoryPage`

Here is my code for creating UI in the admin panel for checkboxing categories in which product will appear (inside the `getCMSFields()` function):

`ProductPage.php`

```
...
$options = CategoryPage::get();
$cb = new CheckboxSetField(
    $name = "categories",
    $title = "Select Categories",
    $source = $options, 
    $value = $this->CategoryPage()
);
$fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Categories", $cb);
...
```

And here is where I set up relation ship in `ProductPage` between it and `CategoryPage`

```
private static $belongs_many_many = array(
    'Categories' => 'CategoryPage'
);
```

And the same for the `CategoryPage`, here is the code:

```
<?php
class CategoryPage extends Page {
   ...
   private static $many_many = array(
    'Products' => 'ProductPage'
   );
  // This function is used to get all products
  // that belong to one or more than one category
  // (thanks to many-many relationship
  public function AllProducts() {
    return $this->Products();
  }
  ...
```

Then if I looping over `$AllProducts` function like this:

```
<% loop $AllProducts %>
  $Title
<% end_loop %>
```

Everything is okay (products are being displayed in the correct categories) until I change my locale to another one (let's say from English to Latvian or Russian).

This is happening because I don't set which product(s) would appear to which categorie(s) in other-than-default locale, so, the actual question would be: How can I access `default_locale`'s relationship in other-than-default locale?

P.S. I have a working website, and why I want to achieve this, is because of amount of products and categories (there are lots of them, so editing every single product and category relationship in every locale that I have would be silly)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In the past I've called `$Master.RelationName` in the layout/template, that may work. So your loop would be something like:

```
<% loop $Master.AllProducts %>
    $Title
<% end_loop %>
```

Comment: I've tried this option, but no luck. Now playing around with docs.